# compileSdkPreview 'UpsideDownCake' after add this my release apk not working?

Tags: android, build.gradle

compileSdkPreview 'UpsideDownCake' after add this my release APK not working in code application in run in emulator but if  I am creating release  APK than than is is not install in my phone and give error app not installed as package appears to be invalid
I dont about upsidedowncake

I and trying everything but nothing happen

Comment: same error, i chnaged targetSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"  now get error like "there was a problem parsing package "

did you solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

**Issue started when**
I updated the dependencies to resolve some incompatibility issues. All dependencies were updated to the latest.
Both compileSDKversion and targetSDKversion "33"

To resolve an error around "androidx.core:core-ktx:+" and targeting SDk 33, I used **compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"** in the build,gradle. Error resolved. That was the issue. App installs when connected to the device using USB but won't install when I generate an APK to test.

Temp solution:
Downgraded all the dependencies to version compatible with targetSdkVersion 32 and kept both compile and target SDK to 32.

Answer (score 0):

Set `compileSdk 33`and `targetSdk 33` to resolve that issue. Most probably, the Play Store doesn't accept code compiled with a preview sdk.